# What is the purpose of the percent sign in contextual filters?

Tags: views

The percent sign is something I once saw in contextual filters in Drupal 6 and Drupal 7, but not Drupal 8.

What is the purpose of the percent sign in contextual filters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The percent sign in view arguments is to tell Drupal to expect a contextual filter within the view path. It is specific to Drupal 6 and 7, linux doesn't matter.

Drupal 8 uses curly braces to accomplish this instead.

From https://www.drupal.org/node/1578576, the example provided is that `user/%/comments` would provide a contextual filter to show the comments for the specific user.

This resource gives screenshots and examples about how to create a contextual view filter:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1578564

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can see the `User ID` in contextual filter which we use in our view path, i.e see in the `Path` settings : "/user/%/profile".

This is an example for you to understand how to use % in view's path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on your view page path, it tells you:

[image]

and as you can tell from the screenshot, it is still used in Drupal 8.

If you still do not understand, basically it is a place holder. Whatever the `%` value is, it gets passed for your contextual filter.

Ex: view path of `hello/%`

When you go to `yoursite.com/hello/benia`, it automatically passes the word `benia` to your contextual filter.

Ex2: in `/user/%/profile` when you go to `/user/10/profile` it atomically passes the `10` to your contextual filter, thus only the stuff related to User ID of `10` shows up.

You could go to `/user/sdlfkjlsadfklsdfja/profile` and it passes `sdlfkjlsadfklsdfja` to your contextual filter, but since this value is no good, nothing shows up in your view page.